# How do I change the text interpreter in sprintf

Tags: matlab

I am writing a script that reads in a directory of files, processes them, and then writes the results back to disk. Since it's a long operation (typically 4000 files or more), I am using the `waitbar` function to show progress:

```
files = dir('*.bin');
h = waitbar(0,sprintf('Processing (0/%u)',K));
K = numel(files);
for k = 1:K
    filename = files(k).name;
    waitbar(k/K,h,sprintf('Processing %s (%u/%u)',filename,k,K));
    % do stuff to file and save
end
delete(h);
```

That's all well and good, except the filenames all contain underscores, and so when `sprintf` renders the `waitbar` label, the TeX interpreter changes them all to subscripts. If I were using the `text` command for a figure, I'd specify `'Interpreter','none'`, but `sprintf` does not appear to have that option.

I know I can globally change the interpreter, but I use the TeX interpreter in other parts of the loop to display annotated data on a figure, so I'd prefer to only change it locally. Is there a way to change the interpreter for just my waitbar title?

Comment: What about escaping the underscores instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` has no interpreter, as it has nothing to do with the display. The bit you need to look at is `waitbar`.

An alternative to changing the interpreter would be to replace any instances of `_` with `\_` - that is, use the escape character.

This could be done like so:

```
waitbar(k/K,h,strrep(sprintf('Processing %s (%u/%u)',filename,k,K), '_', '\_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alan pointed out, `sprintf` has nothing to do with the display of text. You can set the `Interpreter` property of your displaying text object to `none`.

In the `waitbar` case, the text object of interest is its `title` object:

```
hw = waitbar(0, 'Example');
ht = get(get(hw, 'CurrentAxes'), 'title');
set(ht, 'Interpreter', 'none');
waitbar(1, hw, 'Please \do not_interpret me!');
```